# msql like function logical or

Tags: mysql, sql-like

```
select town_id,name from `soft_uni`.towns
where name like 'b%' or 'm%' or 'k%' or 'e%'
```

I want to find all of the names that start with b or m or k or e, but like that it only works for the towns that start with b

Comment: Nothing exists like this for LIKE unfortunately.  For equals, you can do `WHERE IN ('b', 'm', 'k', 'e')` but that type of syntax doesn't work for LIKE.  You have to explicitly put `field LIKE value` for every possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `name like` before you start a condition in that query

```
select town_id,name from `soft_uni`.towns
where name like 'b%' or name like 'm%' or name like 'k%' 
      or name like 'e%'
```

Another solution would be to use `REGEXP`

```
select town_id, name from `soft_uni`.towns
where name REGEXP '^(b|m|k|e)';
```

Comment: it works, but isn't there a shoter way to type it, like a logical or inside of the ' ' this quotation marks, something like  ` '%b|%m'` , i.e starts with b or starts with m